# Match string with multiple patterns by regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of string:
How to return strings end with 'Low' or end with 'High'  or start with 'NQ_'?

```
list=[
 'ES_Low',
 'NQ_High',
 'NQ_Low',
 'NQ_Close',
 'NQ_Volume',
 'GC_Open',
 'GC_High',
 'GC_Volume']

AnswerDesired=[
     'ES_Low',
     'NQ_High',
     'NQ_Low',
     'NQ_Close',
     'NQ_Volume',
     'GC_High']
```

Comment: Start by reading the "[Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)"; the alternation metacharacter (`|`) is the first in the "[More Metacharacters](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#more-metacharacters)" section.  Refer to the [`re` module's docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) as needed.  Or, if you _only_ need to worry about starts and endings, check out the string [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) methods.

Comment: No need for regular expressions here. Use a list comprehension with `startswith()` and `endswith()`.

Comment: @Jan:  Touche...  Got me while I was editing.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase: Provided an example, but OP does not seem to respond anymore ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments: not really a need for regular expressions here.

```
lst=[
 'ES_Low',
 'NQ_High',
 'NQ_Low',
 'NQ_Close',
 'NQ_Volume',
 'GC_Open',
 'GC_High',
 'GC_Volume']

def cleanse(item):
    if item.endswith('Low') \
    or item.endswith('High') \
    or item.startswith('NQ_'):
        return True

desired = list(filter(cleanse, lst))
print(desired)
# ['ES_Low', 'NQ_High', 'NQ_Low', 'NQ_Close', 'NQ_Volume', 'GC_High']
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/PJFVI2) additionally.

---

Of course, the same can be achieved with regular expression as well:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'(?:^NQ_)|(?:(?:Low|High)$)')
desired = [item for item in lst if rx.search(item)]
print(desired)
# ['ES_Low', 'NQ_High', 'NQ_Low', 'NQ_Close', 'NQ_Volume', 'GC_High']
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code will do that,

```
import re
list=['ES_Low','NQ_High','NQ_Low','NQ_Close','NQ_Volume','GC_Open','GC_High','GC_Volume']
for i in list:
    if (re.search("^NQ_|Low$|High$", i)):
        print i
```

Output:

```
ES_Low
NQ_High
NQ_Low
NQ_Close
NQ_Volume
GC_High
```

Comment: You do not need the `.+` before the `$` if you'd use `re.search()`.